Why does scanning a barcode off a mobile phone screen work?
I recently went to a store and showed the loyalty card on a picture taken on my phone. As the cashier moved to scan the barcode, I figured that this won't work.
Laser light is presumably coming out of the scanner and the black bars of the barcode don't reflect it while the white bars do. But on a phone screen, the only difference between black and white is light coming out of the screen, while the display reflects the same, at least based on a quick test (I looked at the shiny spot made by the reflection of light from a lamp off the display showing a checkerboard pattern; it was uniform).
But then the cashier scanned the barcode and it worked. Why is that? Do barcode scanners work differently than I think? Or mobile displays?
If it makes any difference, the phone's display is AMOLED.

This is more of an engineering question than a physics question, but I will answer it here anyways. Source: am engineer and have worked with barcode readers for 10 years.
The short answer: All 2d barcode readers use cameras So their "scanner" is just taking a picture of your phone and running an algorithm over the image.
The longer answer: There is a huge variety of barcodes that are currently in use and defunct codes that are no longer used. They vary in physical size, encoding capacity, and error correction. The most commonly used types nowadays are:

128 one dimensional barcode (grocery store)
QR code - 2 dimensional barcode (links, menus, generic stuff)
Data matrix - 2 dimensional barcode (Mail industry, pcb etching..)

Old style scanner would indeed use a laser beam reflecting off a rotating mirror to "scan" the target. They were called Laser Scanners and you don't see them around anymore. It is likely that if someone tried to use one if these to scan your phone it would fail.
Next but still aged is the CCD Reader. To the best of my knowledge, these are still only used for 1d barcodes. More often than not, I see them coupled with a
CMOS scanner. This is basically a camera with a clever algorithm. Just about all of the latest models of scanners now implement this technology. It is easier to find, more robust, and more flexible. So in all likelihood, your phone was "scanned" by a camera and it works just like you can take a picture of someone else's phone.
An example of a very common handheld scanner is the Honeywell 1900 Series. The red bar light that is presented is usually used for targeting, but can also cycle through intensities to present the camera with better contrast. These scanners or close variants are common in grocery stores and hospitals. From the manual:



Interesting! Does this kind of camera scanner also use a laser for illumination? I remember this particular case involved a scanner that produced red laser light (the kind you see in grocery stores), and the barcode was 1D.

@Kotlopou Yes and for targeting. You may not see it, but the light from the scanner is quickly varying as the camera tries to get a match. These scanners can handle multiple different code types an distances at the same time. This means they cycle through stored algorithms and light intensities until they get a match. This procedure is the same for 2d and 3d barcodes.

@Kotlopou An extremely common scanner I see in the US is the Honeywell xenon 1500 series. Tou should recognize it from grocery stores and hospitals. While it does present a red bar for illumination, the recognition happens through a camera.

@Kotlopou I updated the answer. If you have any other questions, just let me know.
